# On my .htaccess file RewriteRule on Joomla 2.5

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

i'm working on a site developed on Joomla 2.X and I have a simple problem editing .htaccess file...

I just want to use this url http://rumarcedeira.com/acceso-usuarios
But the paged loaded should be this http://rumarcedeira.com/component/hikashop/user/form

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/acceso-usuarios$ /component/hikashop/user/form/ [L,R]
```

But it doesn't work... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

read from this url.. https://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_%28security%29
it seem there is more option you should enter.. 
**Options +FollowSymLinks**
perhaps the answer??